# How to use custom guard and avoid the default guard

Tags: laravel, jwt

This is how my config/auth.php looks like.

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
  'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],
  'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'provider' =>  App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],
        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

And this is how I defined the guard in my controller:

```
 if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials,['guard' => 'admin'])) {
                    return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 400);
                }
```

Problem is I have customized admin guard and defined the model that I wanna use but It's looking for default guard and when it does it avoids the custom guard and use default guards providers User model(Which I want to avoid) . To get rid of it I removed the default api guard and now it's saying api guard not defined. If I define I only can use one guard and can't use my customize guard. How can I avoid the default guard and use other two guard ?

Answer (score 1):

In admin controller,

```
public function __construct(){
            \Config::set('auth.defaults.guard','admin');
        }
```

In manager controller,

```
 public function __construct(){
        \Config::set('auth.defaults.guard','manager');
    }
```

This solved the problem!

Comment: Nice job. Happy coding.